# Pass objects between libraries in Python cffi

Tags: python, python-cffi

If I make a new struct with `cffi.FFI.new`, how do I pass it to a function from a different `FFI` that has the same struct definition?

I have a basic C struct that I am using in Python via the cffi package that I want to pass to various functions generated and compiled by cffi at runtime. However, I do not know how to get the generated functions to share the same struct definition so that I can pass objects between them. cffi does not like it when building an object with one `FFI` and passing it to a function from another `FFI`.

Here is a simplified runnable example of the struct definition and creating an instance in Python:

```
from cffi import FFI

common_header = """
typedef struct {
  int32_t a;
  double b;
} my_struct;
"""

# FFI for building objects
ffibuilder = FFI()
ffibuilder.cdef(common_header)

# Build an object in Python
my_object = ffibuilder.new('my_struct*')
my_object.a = 3
my_object.b = 2.0
```

I have an external library that generates the source code of functions that take pointers to instances of this struct. I currently compile them using the API-mode of CFFI. The important thing here is that the functions may be generated after the objects have been constructed, so I cannot simply collect all the functions together ahead of time and compile them as one library.

```
# Builder for functions generated at runtime
def build_library(header: str, source: str):
    from tempfile import TemporaryDirectory

    ffitemp = FFI()

    ffitemp.cdef(common_header + header)

    ffitemp.set_source('_temp', source)

    with TemporaryDirectory() as temp_dir:
        lib_path = ffitemp.compile(tmpdir=temp_dir)

        lib = ffitemp.dlopen(lib_path)

    return lib.func


# Use function
header = """
int func(my_struct *A);
"""

source = """
typedef struct {
  int32_t a;
  double b;
} my_struct;

int func(my_struct *A) {
    return A -> a;
}
"""

func = build_library(header, source)
```

When I try to pass instances of my struct to the function, I get an error saying that the struct I am passing in is not the same type as the one accepted by the function.

```
# Use function
a = func(my_object)
print(a)

TypeError: initializer for ctype 'my_struct *' appears indeed to be 
'my_struct *', the types are different (check that you are not e.g. 
mixing up different ffi instances)
```

The error is pretty clear about why it is unhappy. It does not like that I have constructed `my_object` using `ffibuilder` and passed it to a function defined in a different `FFI`, which has its own definition of the `my_struct` type.

How do I get the compilation of the generated functions to share a struct definition with a central FFI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `FFI.include` to include the source and definitions of one `FFI` instance in another. Objects constructed with the included `FFI` are passable to functions in the `FFI` in which it was included.

Note that an included definition cannot be duplicated in later `FFI`. Also, an `FFI` can only be included if `set_source` has been called on it. This is true even if all you want is the header; in which case, simply set the source to an empty string.

Here is setting the empty source on the main `FFI`:

```
from cffi import FFI

common_header = """
typedef struct {
  int32_t a;
  double b;
} my_struct;
"""

# FFI for building objects
ffibuilder = FFI()
ffibuilder.cdef(common_header)
ffibuilder.set_source('_main', '')  # <-- Set empty source
```

And here is including the main `FFI` in the leaf `FFI`:

```
# Builder for functions generated at runtime
def build_library(header: str, source: str):
    from tempfile import TemporaryDirectory

    ffitemp = FFI()

    ffitemp.include(ffibuilder)  # <-- include main FFI

    ffitemp.cdef(header)

    ffitemp.set_source('_temp', source)

    with TemporaryDirectory() as temp_dir:
        lib_path = ffitemp.compile(tmpdir=temp_dir)

        lib = ffitemp.dlopen(lib_path)

    return lib.func
```